# Problems running jetty & HTTP2 on Google App Engine

Tags: apple-push-notifications, jetty, http2

We have been using Apple Push Notifications successfully for the past 2-3 years. We use a Google App Engine implementation to generate the push requests which we send to the Apple Push Notifcation Service.

However Apple now requires users to migrate from legacy protocols to a new HTTP/2-based Apple Push Notification service (APNs). As you can see from https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=c88acm2b the deadline for the migration to be completed is March 31 2021.

We have implemented the necessary migration within our Google App Engine project. We have replaced the older apns apis with jetty http/2. We have successfully sent requests to the Apple server but ONLY when running our server locally on our windows 10 Eclipse development environment.

However when we upload the application to the Google Cloud we receive the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Client ALPNProcessors!
org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.FutureResponseListener.getResult(FutureResponseListener.java:118)
org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.FutureResponseListener.get(FutureResponseListener.java:101)
org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpRequest.send(HttpRequest.java:729)
com.xxx.AppleHttp2.perform(AppleHttp2.java:50)
com.xxx.OurNotifications.sendAPNSMsg(OurNotifications.java:257)
com.xxx.OurNotifications.sendAPNSMessage(OurNotifications.java:215)
com.xxx.OurNotifications.sendMessage(OurNotifications.java:82)
com.xxx.ServletHelper.send(ServletHelper.java:227)
```

Here is an extract from our Maven pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-client</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.34.v20201102</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.http2</groupId>
    <artifactId>http2-client</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.34.v20201102</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.http2</groupId>
    <artifactId>http2-http-client-transport</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.34.v20201102</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-alpn-openjdk8-client</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.34.v20201102</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mortbay.jetty.alpn/alpn-boot -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty.alpn</groupId>
    <artifactId>alpn-boot</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.13.v20181017</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

As mentioned above, this works locally within Eclipse. However it does not work when upload to the Google App Engine Server
```

Please can you help?

Regards, Michael

-----EDIT 2 MAR 2021 START-------

We have now followed sbordet's advice and read the helpful article https://webtide.com/jetty-alpn-java-8u252/

We have attempted to follow its recommendations by changing the dependencies in the eclipse POM file as shown in the extract below.
As you can see we have changed the versions in all the dependencies apart from the server one. The (final - org.mortbay.jetty.alpn) server dependency we replaced with jetty-alpn-openjdk8-server.

As you will appreciate we are developing on Eclipse/Maven and deploying to the GAE. We are required to use Maven to supply the jars.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
<artifactId>jetty-client</artifactId>
<version>9.4.28.v20200408</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.http2</groupId>
<artifactId>http2-client</artifactId>
<version>9.4.28.v20200408</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.http2</groupId>
<artifactId>http2-http-client-transport</artifactId>
<version>9.4.28.v20200408</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
<artifactId>jetty-alpn-openjdk8-client</artifactId>
<version>9.4.28.v20200408</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-alpn-openjdk8-server -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-alpn-openjdk8-server</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.28.v20200408</version>
</dependency>
```

However when we upload and run on the Google App Engine server we see the following failure. Please can you help.

```
org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
oejus.SslContextFactory:Request550E3245: x509=X509@6cd9979d
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Client ALPNProcessors!
org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.FutureResponseListener.getResult(FutureResponseListener.java:118)
org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.FutureResponseListener.get(FutureResponseListener.java:101)
org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpRequest.send(HttpRequest.java:713)
com.xxx.AppleHttp2.perform(AppleHttp2.java:48)
com.xxx.OurNotifications.sendAPNSMsg(OurNotifications.java:45)
com.xxx.OurNotifications.sendAPNSMessage(OurNotifications.java:28)
com.xxx.SendMessageTestServlet.doPost(SendMessageTestServlet.java:37)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:848)
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1780) com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1767)
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.ParseBlobUploadHandler.handle(ParseBlobUploadHandler.java:111)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1182)
com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppEngineWebAppContext.doHandle(AppEngineWebAppContext.java:187)
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:513)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:293)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:539)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:333)
com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnection.handle(RpcConnection.java:216)
com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnector.serviceRequest(RpcConnector.java:81)
com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:134)
com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:772)
com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:735)
com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:705)
com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:261)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Client ALPNProcessors!
org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.client.ALPNClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ALPNClientConnectionFactory.java:54)
org.eclipse.jetty.http2.client.http.HttpClientTransportOverHTTP2.newConnection(HttpClientTransportOverHTTP2.java:159)
org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslClientConnectionFactory.newConnection(SslClientConnectionFactory.java:130)
org.eclipse.jetty.http2.client.http.HttpClientTransportOverHTTP2.lambda$doStart$1(HttpClientTransportOverHTTP2.java:109)
org.eclipse.jetty.http2.client.HTTP2Client$ClientSelectorManager.newConnection(HTTP2Client.java:476)
org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.createEndPoint(ManagedSelector.java:271)
org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.access$1800(ManagedSelector.java:62)
org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$CreateEndPoint.run(ManagedSelector.java:933)
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
... 1 more

Suppressed: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/jetty/alpn/java/client/JDK9ClientALPNProcessor has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApplicationClassLoader.findClass(ApplicationClassLoader.java:135)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:349)
java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:370)
java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.client.ALPNClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ALPNClientConnectionFactory.java:62)

... 10 more

Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/alpn/ALPN
org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.openjdk8.client.OpenJDK8ClientALPNProcessor.init(OpenJDK8ClientALPNProcessor.java:68)
org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.client.ALPNClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ALPNClientConnectionFactory.java:74)

... 10 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.ALPN
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApplicationClassLoader.findClass(ApplicationClassLoader.java:135)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

... 12 more
```

-----EDIT 2 MAR 2021 END-------

Comment: You need to specify the exact JVM vendor and version that you are using, as ALPN is sensitive to that. For Java 8u242 and earlier you need some configuration, for later versions a different one.

Comment: Hello sbordet. Thank you for responding.

Comment: When running the GAE locally, launched from Eclipse on my Win 10 PC, I specify jdk1.8.0_261. I believe the vendor is Oracle.  This is compatible with the version of Jetty ALPN specified in my POM dependency above.

However we do not know what version of the JVM is being run in GAE cloud standard environment or whether we can specify a different version. We believe the GAE is using JVM version 1.8 (i.e. Java 8). Can you tell us what version of the JVM is being used by the GAE standard environment? Also do you know the compatible version of Jetty ALPN?

Regards, Michael

Comment: Read: https://webtide.com/jetty-alpn-java-8u252/.

Comment: Thank you sborder. Please see my edits above. Please can you advise?

Comment: Troubleshooting questions like this one are not suited for StackOverflow. I recommend that you open an issue to the Jetty project (https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues) and discuss it there. Your "question" lacks too much information to be able to help you.

Comment: I have posted this issue to GitHub, as requested.
https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/6042